# Things stop working if I use Serial.println(tt) and when I use display.drawPixel(i - ii, 64 - Harray[ii], SSD1306_WHITE);

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, display

Things stop working if I use line 131 `Serial.println(tt);` and when I use line 145 `display.drawPixel(i - ii, 64 - Harray[ii], SSD1306_WHITE);` Also Serial Monitor gives very strange reading. Serial monitor is 9600 baud.

```cpp
//Kamil Mambetov
//Feb 17 2023
//sht31 with display and plot on it.

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_SHT31.h"

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128  // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64

uint8_t loopCnt = 0;
uint8_t i = 0;
int Tarray[128] = {};
int Harray[128] = {};
float tmax = 0;
float tmin = 0;
float hmax = 0;
float hmin = 0;

Adafruit_SHT31 sht31 = Adafruit_SHT31();

// Declaration for SSD1306 display connected using software SPI (default case):
#define OLED_MOSI 11
#define OLED_CLK 13
#define OLED_DC 9
#define OLED_CS 10
#define OLED_RESET 8
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                        OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);


void setup() {
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC);
  //u8g2_for_adafruit_gfx.begin(display);  // connect u8g2 procedures to Adafruit GFX

  Serial.begin(9600);

  while (!Serial)
    delay(10);  // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until serial console opens

  Serial.println("SHT31 test");
  if (!sht31.begin(0x44)) {  // Set to 0x45 for alternate i2c addr
    Serial.println("Couldn't find SHT31");
    while (1) delay(1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1);               // Normal 1:1 pixel scale
  display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);  // Draw white text
  display.setCursor(0, 0);              // Start at top-left corner
  display.cp437(true);                  // Use full 256 char 'Code Page 437' font

  float t = sht31.readTemperature();
  float h = sht31.readHumidity();

  if (t > tmax or tmax == 0) {
    tmax = t;
  } else if (t < tmin or tmin == 0) {
    tmin = t;
  }

  if (h > hmax or hmax == 0) {
    hmax = h;
  } else if (h < hmin or hmin == 0) {
    hmin = h;
  }

  char *Tchar = "";
  char *Hchar = "";
  char *Tmaxchar = "";
  char *Hmaxchar = "";
  char *Tminchar = "";
  char *Hminchar = "";

  display.setCursor(0, 0);  // start writing at this position
  //display.print("t:");
  //display.setCursor(12, 0);
  dtostrf(t, 4, 1, Tchar);
  display.print(Tchar);

  display.setCursor(30, 0);
  display.print("max:");
  display.setCursor(52, 0);
  dtostrf(tmax, 4, 1, Tmaxchar);
  display.print(Tmaxchar);

  display.setCursor(78, 0);
  display.print("min:");
  display.setCursor(100, 0);
  dtostrf(tmin, 4, 1, Tminchar);
  display.print(Tminchar);

  display.setCursor(0, 8);
  //display.print("h:");
  //display.setCursor(12, 8);
  dtostrf(h, 4, 1, Hchar);
  display.print(Hchar);

  display.setCursor(30, 8);
  display.print("max:");
  display.setCursor(52, 8);
  dtostrf(hmax, 4, 1, Hmaxchar);
  display.print(Hmaxchar);

  display.setCursor(78, 8);
  display.print("min:");
  display.setCursor(100, 8);
  dtostrf(hmin, 4, 1, Hminchar);
  display.print(Hminchar);

  // display.drawPixel(x, t, SSD1306_WHITE); //draw single pixel
  //Serial.println(h);
  // Serial.print("aaa");
  //Serial.println(t);
  // Serial.print("ttt");
  //float to int conversion
  int tt = 0;
  int hh = 0;
  tt = int(t);
  float c = 0;
  c = h/2;
  hh = int(c);
  //Serial.println(c);
  Serial.println(tt);

  //plot
  i++;
  loopCnt++;

  Tarray[i] = tt;
  Harray[i] = hh;
  //Serial.println(Harray[i]);

  int ii = 0;
  while (ii < i) {
    ii++;
    display.drawPixel(i - ii, 64 - Tarray[ii], SSD1306_WHITE);
    //display.drawPixel(i - ii, 64 - Harray[ii], SSD1306_WHITE);
  }

  if (i == 128) {
    i = 0;
  }

  display.display();  // make everything visible
  delay(2000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding your question about code formatting, you can see what I did in the side-by-side markdown view in the [revisions](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/posts/92294/revisions) on the question. In short triple-back-tics before and after the code. The editor has help under the question mark in the circle in the upper right. You can also indent the code with spaces, but that's somewhat more painful to work with and the language used cannot be hinted.